# While training RLHF model I am getting error like, ValueError: num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples=0

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, large-language-model, google-generativeai

I am using above code for training RLHF for answer generation.

```
learning_rate=1.41e-5
max_ppo_epochs=1
mini_batch_size=4
batch_size=16

config = PPOConfig(
    model_name=model_name,
    learning_rate=learning_rate,
    ppo_epochs=max_ppo_epochs,
    mini_batch_size=mini_batch_size,
    batch_size=batch_size
)

ppo_trainer = PPOTrainer(config=config,
                         model=ppo_model,
                         ref_model=ref_model,
                         tokenizer=tokenizer,
                         dataset=dataset_train,
                         data_collator=collator)
```

but while running this code I am getting error like

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-5fa467fb1768> in <cell line: 14>()
     12 )
     13 
---> 14 ppo_trainer = PPOTrainer(config=config,
     15                          model=ppo_model,
     16                          ref_model=ref_model,

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/utils/data/sampler.py in __init__(self, data_source, replacement, num_samples, generator)
    141 
    142         if not isinstance(self.num_samples, int) or self.num_samples <= 0:
--> 143             raise ValueError(f"num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples={self.num_samples}")
    144 
    145     @property

ValueError: num_samples should be a positive integer value, but got num_samples=0
```

How to solve this error? Thanks in advance.